# Deployment of metadata between 2 orgs using ANT

Tags: apex, deployment, ant

I'm deploying custom objects data from OrgA o OrgB using ANT tool which left me in never ending scenario on what to deploy 1st. Here is my scenario:

I got OrgA which contains custom fields in Managed package and some custom objects.In OrgB i have only Managed Package objects and fields.I need to deploy these custom fields of Managed Package object & some custom Objects.

1) I got the custom Object data of Managed Package from OrgA which contains few fields having relation with custom object fields.
2) Custom object fields also have an relationship with Managed Package objects.

If i try to deploy Managed Package objects first, it is giving me errors of the fields which is having relationship with custom objects.

If i do the custom Object first, it is also throwing the error of the fields having an relationship with custom objects.

Is there any better approach available? I'm looking for a sample.xml which gives me all objects(including custom fields) of a managed package and all custom objects of an org?

Note: Above custom or Managed objects includes custom fields, buttons(reference to apex pages)

Comment: What about deploying them together?

Comment: All Managed package objects at once and Custom Objects at once.

Comment: But I mean all together, using same package.xml

Comment: Yes. All Managed objects in one package.xml and custom in another package.xml

Comment: And why do not include Managed and other in same package.xml?

Comment: If i retrieve Managed & unmanaged package at same time in build.xml, Managed Package objects custom fields are not retrieving.

Comment: I'm looking for a sample.xml which gives me all objects(including custom fields) of a managed package and all custom objects of an org?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. You need to create that by yourself, and specify fields that you are interested in manually

Answer (score 2):

from my site - you can deploy only custom fields from managed packages.

you should add all of standard object to the package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>StandardObject</members>
        <members>Object1_ManagePackage</members>
        <members>Object2_ManagePackage</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
<version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

when you deploy only object/fields you must remember that you should add manuly it to the profile/permision set/ field level security

Please mark this answer if it is helpful for you.